# Call SQL Server Stored procedure with input and output parameter in php

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to run 10 select queries under a single stored procedure and get result of each select query separately using output parameter and display that output to front-end using **php and sqlsrv library**. How to get It?

Comment: By running 10 select statements in your procedure. Each of those would populate one of your output parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basic, but working example.

Database part:

```
USE [TestDatabase]
CREATE PROCEDURE [TestProcedure]
    @P1 int OUTPUT,
    @P2 int OUTPUT,
    @P3 int OUTPUT,
    @P4 int OUTPUT,
    @P5 int OUTPUT,
    @P6 int OUTPUT,
    @P7 int OUTPUT,
    @P8 int OUTPUT,
    @P9 int OUTPUT,
    @P10 int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- It's very basic example.
    -- Put here your own SQL statements, which must return single values
    SELECT @P1 = 1
    SELECT @P2 = 2
    SELECT @P3 = 3
    SELECT @P4 = 4
    SELECT @P5 = 5
    SELECT @P6 = 6
    SELECT @P7 = 7
    SELECT @P8 = 8
    SELECT @P9 = 9
    SELECT @P10 = 10
END
```

PHP part:

```
<?php
// Connection
$server = 'server\instance,port';
$cinfo = array(
    "Database"=>'TestDatabase',
    "UID"=>"User",
    "PWD"=>"Password"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $conn === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Call stored procedure
$sql = '{call TestProcedure(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}';
$p1 = 0;
$p2 = 0;
$p3 = 0;
$p4 = 0;
$p5 = 0;
$p6 = 0;
$p7 = 0;
$p8 = 0;
$p9 = 0;
$p10 = 0;
$params = array(
    array(&$p1, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p2, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p3, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p4, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p5, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p6, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p7, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p8, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p9, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT),
    array(&$p10, SQLSRV_PARAM_INOUT)
);
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

// Output parameters are available after consuming all resultsets.
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);

// Output
echo 'Parameters values'."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 1: '.$p1."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 2: '.$p2."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 3: '.$p3."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 4: '.$p4."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 5: '.$p5."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 6: '.$p6."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 7: '.$p7."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 8: '.$p8."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 9: '.$p9."</br>";
echo 'Parameter 10: '.$p10."</br>";
?>
```

Comment: After running the code with the solution provided by you I got an error as
"Procedure or function sp_get has too many arguments specified."
Here sp_get is the stored procedure name.

Comment: @Hariprasad Advids Can you show the procedure code? Or, what is the number of parameters?

Comment: there are total 10 parameters and i want to pass emp id to each sql query as input parameter

Comment: @Hariprasad Advids  It's very difficult for me to tell you what this error is. I must have at least your params definitions, as they are defined in stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do this in PHP, but you can generally replace output parameters with resultsets, which don't require any special client APIs.

EG

```
declare @count1  int = (select count(*) from sys.objects)
declare @count2  int = (select count(*) from sys.columns)

select * 
from (values ('count1', @count1),('count2', @count2) ) as t(pn,pv)
```